# Reference request: Affine Grassmannian and G-bundles 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$ of zero characteristic. The set of cosets $X_G=G(k((t))/G(k[[t]])$ is called the Affine Grassmannian of $G$ and can be given the structure of an ind-$k$-variety, so that for a closed embedding of groups $H\to G$, we get a natural morphism $X_H\to X_G$, which is a closed embedding if $G/H$ is affine. I am interested in a (as detailed as possible) reference for this, but from a specific perspective as will be explain in the following.

There are several possible (equivalent) constructions. A direct approach, in the language of ind-varieties, can be found in Kumar's "Infinite grassmannians and Moduli spaces of G-bundles" for example (for a reductive $G$, which is fine for me), which describes the ind-variety structure explicitly. Apart of using some representation theory, that I don't know well enough, it also lacks an explicit universal property which makes it difficult to operate with and in particular to construct morphsims to and from it.

A more abstract approach  is to describe a functor $\operatorname{Gr}_G:kAlg\to Set$ for which $X_G$ is the set of $k$-points. Here is were the $G$-bundles (torsors) appear. There are the "global" and "local" approaches, in which roughly, $\operatorname{Gr}_G (A)$ classifies $A$-families of $G$-Bundles on a curve or a formal disc resp. together with a trivializaion away from a point. Now that one has a functor, it is possible to show that it is an ind-scheme. It is this approach that I would like to have a reference for.

I would like to mention, that this approach is outlined in Gaitsgory's seminar 
[notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Oct13%28AffGr%29.pdf), and a more competent student would probably be able to fill in the details by herself, but unfortunately I find it difficult, so I was hopping there might be a more thorough treatment available.

Comment: If you provide contact information (e.g., a webpage which lists your email address) then I can send you something.  But perhaps someone else will provide a more detailed literature reference (I am not aware of any).

Comment: @nosr, thank you for your help. you can send it to kotelkanim1@gmail.com. 

Comment: I sympathize greatly with your last sentence and I wish I'd done something to formalize all the exercises I did over the years while in grad school, but alas, when it came time to write the thesis it wasn't worth making it even longer to include something "standard"...therein, I suspect, lies the problem.

Comment: I believe your second approach is Proposition 2 (p.505) of Heinloth's "Uniformization of G-bundles." (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00208-009-0443-4)

Comment: There is a description in Mirkovic-Vilonen, but it is missing some details: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401222

Comment: I am looking into all of your suggestions. Btw, why not post them as answers?

Comment: @S. Carnahan: Where in the Mirkovic-Vilonen paper is there anything resembling a proof or precise description about these matters?  All I can find is a very terse discussion in section 1, which doesn't even have precise definitions. Is the matter discussed somewhere else in the paper?

Comment: @nosr: there is a brief global description of the functor in section 5 (about the commutativity constraint), with no proofs.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your second approach is Proposition 2 (p.6) of Heinloth's *Uniformization of $G$-bundles* available from Heinloth's website: http://staff.science.uva.nl/~heinloth/Uniformization_17-8-09.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Another reference with a slightly different approach is Drinfeld & Beilinsons *Quantization of Hitchin Integrable Systems and Hecke Eigensheaves* available online here [link text](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~mitya/langlands/hitchin/BD-hitchin.pdf). The affine Grassmannian is defined in 5.3.11 and it is explained in the previous remark 5.3.10 c. why this is represented by a formally smoooth ind-proper ind-scheme.

Here, the authors keep track of the points away from which the $G$-bundle has a trivialization, this is denoted by $Gr_{X^I}$ and then take the colimit
$colim_{I}Gr_{X^I}$,
where the colimit is taken over the category $\mathbf{fSet}^{op}$ of all finite sets $I$ with surjections between them.

In the language of Gaitsgory in *Contractibility of the Space of Rational Maps* this means that the affine Grassmannian is a pseudo ind-proper pseudo ind-scheme [link text](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1741.pdf). The main point, I think, is that it is possible to define a well-behaved category of D-modules over such pseudo ind-schemes.

Answer (score 2):

The following papers might also be helpful:

G. Faltings, Algebraic loop groups and moduli spaces of bundles, J. Eur. Math. Soc. 5 (2003), 41-68.

G. Pappas, M. Rapoport, Twisted Loop groups and their affine flag varieties, Adv. Math. 219 (2008), no. 1, 118-198

G. Pappas, X. Zhu,  Local models of Shimura varieties and a conjecture of Kottwitz, http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5588v4, to appear in Invent. math.